# Finding all classes whose name matches a string

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I would like to find all ruby classes whose name matches a string(ignoring case).
That means that the string should be a substring of the class name.
So when you search for 'stri' you should get the class `String` (among others) as a result.

Do you know a convenient and not too inefficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class)
.select{|klass| klass.name.downcase.include?("stri".downcase)}

# => [
  String,
  RubyToken::TkDXSTRING,
  RubyToken::TkDSTRING,
  RubyToken::TkXSTRING,
  RubyToken::TkSTRING
]
```

Comment: You should probably downcase `"stri"` as well. And make it a parameter in a method.

Comment: Note that the `ObjectSpace` may contain "stale" objects that should be garbage collected but the garbage collector hasn't run yet. IOW: this method may return classes that don't actually exist anymore.

Comment: @JörgWMittag As long as classes that have a name are concerned, they are assigned to a constant, which means that they are not garbage collected. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'd use a Regexp: `/stri/i === klass.name`, it's shorter and more flexible.

Comment: `class Foo; end; Foo = nil; ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select {|c| c.name == 'Foo' } # => [Foo]` I even tried throwing a `GC.start` in there. As long as you are not *actually* running out of memory, the GC won't run and the class will still be found.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That is very interesting. I prepended the condition with `c.instance_of?(Class) and`, but it looks like it is indeed a class within an iteration, but outside of the iterator, it is not a class.