# Why is an object different inside and outside of an iteration?

Tags: ruby, constants

I assigned a class to a constant `Foo`, and reassigned `Foo` to something else:

```
class Foo; end
Foo = nil
```

In the `main` environment, `Foo` refers to the newly assigned object:

```
p Foo # => nil
```

But, within an iteration of some kind, (I am not sure which), `Foo` refers to the previous object:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select{|c| c.name == "Foo"}
.each{|c| p c, c.instance_of?(Class)}
# => Foo
     true
```

Why is this?

Comment: This came out of a comment by Jörg W Mittag to my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523676).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assigning `nil` to the constant `Foo` doesn't affect the created class. It still exists, although you cannot refer to it with `Foo` anymore (unless you reassign the class object to `Foo` again).

```
class Foo; end
Foo.object_id
# => 70210590718440
Foo = nil
Foo.object_id
# => 4
Foo = ObjectSpace._id2ref(70210590718440)
Foo.object_id
# => 70210590718440
```

Regarding the `name`, creating a class with:

```
class Foo; end
Foo.name
# => "Foo"
```

assigns it to the contant `Foo`, just like:

```
Foo = Class.new
Foo.name
# => "Foo"
```

It also sets its `name`, but this doesn't make it a class. You can as well create classes without a name:

```
foo = Class.new
foo.name
# => nil
```

Assigning an unnamed class to a constant sets its name:

```
Bar = foo
foo.name
# => "Bar"
```

Once set, it doesn't change:

```
Baz = foo
foo.name
# => "Bar"
```

Comment: I got it. I seem to have confused the constant "named" `Foo` and a class whose `name` property is `Foo`. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The class you created exists and is reachable from the main ObjectSpace as long as it is not garbage collected.

The constant name `Foo` is merely a reference to the class object. Its internal name remains "Foo", even if accessed via other variable or constant names.

Try this, to demonstrate that even 'renamed' `a`, the name of the class is still "Foo":

```
class Foo; end
a = Foo
Foo = nil
puts a.name # prints Foo
```

Comment: Does this mean that two different objects can share the same name, and there is some kind of priority that decides which object is referred when called with that name?

Comment: There is only one object here.

Comment: I am mentioning `nil`, which is referred to as `Foo`, and the original class object, which also has the name `Foo`.

Comment: What do you mean by "which also has the name `Foo`"? Objects don't have names in Ruby. Methods and variables have names, but methods and variables aren't objects.

Comment: @sawa You can declare a "Foo" class as many times you want, it still refers to one and only class, features will be appended to it as needed. There is no `name=` method for the `Class` class, trying to create a class dynamically will cause the creation of an anonymous class without possibility to change its name.

Comment: I did not intend the method `name`. I used the word "name" as a cover term for constants and variables.

Comment: I got it. I seem to have confused the constant "named" `Foo` and a class whose `name` property is `Foo`. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`Foo` is bound to `nil`, both inside and outside of the block. What makes you think it isn't? You aren't even referring to `Foo` inside of the block.

Comment: The object inside the block returns `Foo` for its name, and that is a class.

Comment: What does this have to do with the value of the constant `Foo`?

Comment: A capitalized name is a constant.

Comment: A variable that starts with a capital letter is a constant. But the only two variables in your block are `c`, which isn't even a constant, and `Class` which is a constant but isn't `Foo`.

Comment: It is not referred to by any literal expression, but the relevant object `c` has a name `Foo`. (Note that I am avoiding the word "variable" because a constant is not a variable.)

Comment: What does calling the `name` method of the object referred to by `c` have to do with the constant `Foo`?

Comment: I did not intend the method `name`. I just used the word "name" to cover constants and variables.

Comment: But *there is no* variable or constant named `Foo` inside of the block! And yet you claim that the value of `Foo` inside of the block is different than outside, when you don't even *use* `Foo` inside of the block.

Comment: I got it. I seem to have confused the constant "named" `Foo` and a class whose `name` property is `Foo`. Thanks for the help.